# How many megabyte jpeg can be uploaded?

Tags: support, images

Many months ago I bought a home scanner that does just one page per scan. It can do pdfs and jpegs. It also has a variety of choices, in particular I can increase or decrease the number of, um, things per square inch. When I do that, it tells me the expected size of the jpeg in megabytes before I do the scan.

I found that if I go over something like five megabytes and then upload to MSE, it will just sit there happily forever and never upload the image. So I have found the correct options in a few different situations to get an image between one and two megabytes.

Meanwhile, there is a newcomer here  [Uniqueness of shortest distance between the center of two circles (and in higher dimensions)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/244728/uniqueness-of-shortest-distance-between-the-center-of-two-circles-and-in-higher) whom I told to post images, but who cannot seem to work it out.

So I suppose the main question is, what would you guess as the maximum file size for an uploadable jpeg on MSE? There does seem to be some intermediate service involved, something about imgur.

$$\begin{array}{l}\text{How many roads must a man walk down}\cr
\text{Before you call him a man?}\cr
\text{Yes, ’n’ how many seas must a white dove sail}\cr
\text{Before she sleeps in the sand?}\cr
\text{Yes, ’n’ how many times must the cannonballs fly}\cr
\text{Before they’re forever banned?}\cr
\text{The answer, my friend, is blowin’ in the wind}\cr
\text{The answer is blowin’ in the wind}\end{array}$$

Comment: My guess is that some $q\in\mathbb Q$ megabytes. Probably $q>0$, and my guess is that $q<10^{80}$, but not much more than that.

Comment: @Asaf, you are a never-failing lantern behind my back.

Comment: No wonder, if so, that you keep fumbling in the dark! :-)

Comment: @Asaf, the author of that bit is not well known, first http://dev.iwise.com/Ernest_Bramah/Friends%20and%20Friendship  A personal favorite: "There are few situations in life that cannot be honourably settled, and without loss of time, either by suicide, a bag of gold, or by thrusting a despised antagonist over the edge of a precipice upon a dark night."  See http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Ernest_Bramah

Comment: @AsafKaragila Why is the number of megabytes rational?

Comment: @BenjaLim: Why shouldn't it be?